# chaining together successive matches in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a set of authors and a set of articles. They are related using the [:WROTE] relationship. A single article can have one or more authors, and an author can write one or more articles.

I want to find how many of the top ten articles in terms of number of authors has the most productive author listed as a coauthor.

I can find the top author using

```
MATCH (author:Author)-[:WROTE]->(article:Article) 
WITH author, COUNT(article) as numberofarticles, collect(article) as articles
ORDER BY numberofarticles DESC LIMIT 1
RETURN author, numberofarticles, EXTRACT(n in articles | n.title) AS extracted
```

and similarly, I can find the top 10 articles in terms of authors using

```
MATCH (author:Author)-[:WROTE]->(article:Article) 
WITH article, COUNT(author) as numberofauthors
ORDER BY numberofauthors DESC LIMIT 10
RETURN article.title, numberofauthors
```

However, I am stuck here. As the match is the same I have though of creating two collections, the collection of authors and the collection of articles

```
MATCH (author:Author)-[:WROTE]->(article:Article)
WITH collect(author) as authors, COUNT(author) as numberofauthors, collect(article) as toparticles, COUNT(article) as numberofarticles
```

but now I'n stuck in sorting the collections to find the top 10 articles by author count and top author by article count. I tried a bunch of different things, but I'm not getting any closer. Any help would be appreciated.

Regards, Richard

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this will work:

```
MATCH (author:Author)-[:WROTE]->(article:Article)
WITH author, count(article) ORDER BY count(article) DESC
WITH collect(author)[0] AS top_author

MATCH (article:Article)<-[:WROTE]-(author:Author)
WITH top_author, article, count(author) ORDER BY count(author) DESC
WITH top_author, collect(article)[0..10] AS top_10_article

MATCH top_author-[rel:WROTE]->top_10_article
RETURN count(rel)
```

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. 

`MATCH (article:Article)<-[:WROTE]-(author:Author)
WITH article, count(author) AS numberofauthors ORDER BY numberofauthors DESC LIMIT 10
WITH collect(article)[0..10] AS top_10_articles
RETURN EXTRACT(n in top_10_articles | n.title) AS title`

returns a different result to 

`MATCH (article:Article)<-[:WROTE]-(author:Author) RETURN article.title, count(author) AS numberofauthors ORDER BY numberofauthors DESC LIMIT 10`